# Changing width of connectors to a specific object in Visio with VBA

Tags: vba, visio

I'm trying to create a macro to change the thickness of connectors that are connected to a specific block. This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub HighlightPaths_Click()

Dim selection As Shape
Dim connections() As Long
Dim i As Integer

'Msgbox glued shapes
If ActiveWindow.selection.Count = 0 Then

MsgBox ("Select a shape then click this button.")

Else

'Set shape to current selection
Set selection = ActiveWindow.selection(1)

'Get array of connectors on selected object
connections() = selection.GluedShapes(visGluedShapesAll1D, "")

'Resize connectors to that shape [ERROR HERE]   
For i = 0 To UBound(connections())
    connections(i).Cells("LineWeight").Formula = "0.5 pt"
Next

End If
End Sub
```

I know this comes from the fact that I'm trying to access the Cells property in a type that is not applicable. Do I have to search for the returns of the Glue method in the list of master shapes to find the dynamic connector master shapes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array connections(), contains connected shapes IDs. 
You need get shape object, before change it Line Weight.

> ActivePage.Shapes(connections(i)).Cells("LineWeight").Formula = "0.5 pt"