# In Visio VBA, How do I read and set the weight of a connector

Tags: vba, visio

I tried saving a macro where I set the weight of a connector, and got an expression like

`Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(17).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineWeight).FormulaU = "6 pt"`

I wrote this:

```
    For Each conn In Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Connects
        conn.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineWeight).FormulaU = "6 pt"
    Next
```

I get an error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method".

In the Microsoft documentation, I could find no mention of how to read and set the weight of a connector. The documentation page for the Connect object https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.connect for example, contains no references to any style attributes.

EDIT ****************************************

After reading the suggestions, I remain perplexed.

1. I looked up [Changing width of connectors to a specific object in Visio with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288324/changing-width-of-connectors-to-a-specific-object-in-visio-with-vba), as suggested. I tried `ActivePage.shapes(connections(1)).Cells("LineWeight").Formula = "10 pt"` (in the answer, it's connections(i) ),  I get an error `sub or function not defined` on the `connections(1)` part.
2. I tried using FromSheet. I did

```
For Each connnn In Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Connects 
         shp = connnn.FromSheet 
         Debug.Print ("shp.Type=" + CStr(shp.Type)) 
        Debug.Print (shp.Type = visObjTypeConnect)
        shp.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineWeight).FormulaU = "10 pt"
Next
```

I get an "object required" error.

3. I tried setting ALL shapes to a line width of "10 pt". That works!
4. So I tried filtering for connectors, as follows:

```
    Set allShapes = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.shapes
    For Each shp In allShapes
        Debug.Print ("shp.Type=" + CStr(shp.Type))
        Debug.Print (shp.Type = visObjTypeConnect)
        If shp.Type = visObjTypeConnect Then
            shp.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineWeight).FormulaU = "10 pt"
        End If
    Next
```

No changes, see output below. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.visobjecttypes, 3 means visObjTypeApp, 4 means visObjTypeCell, and 2 isn't listed (visObjTypeConnect being 8):

- shp.Type=2
- False
- shp.Type=3
- False
- shp.Type=3
- False
- shp.Type=4
- False
- (more of the same)

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this one: [Changing width of connectors to a specific object in Visio with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288324/changing-width-of-connectors-to-a-specific-object-in-visio-with-vba) ??

Comment: **LineWeight** is a property of the [Shape object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape), not the [Connect object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.connect)

Comment: [Retrieve a Connect object from the Connects collection returned by the Connects and FromConnects properties of a **Shape** object, or from the Page.Connects or Master.Connects property.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.connect#:~:text=Retrieve%20a%20Connect%20object%20from%20the%20Connects%20collection%20returned%20by%20the%20Connects%20and%20FromConnects%20properties%20of%20a%20Shape%20object%2C%20or%20from%20the%20Page.Connects%20or%20Master.Connects%20property.)

Comment: Page.Connects are NOT connectors. They are "junctions" (i.e. points where a connector connects to a shape). I.e. a "connect" is not the same as a "connector". A "connect" is a connection point (a point where connector connects to a shape)

Comment: To get a connector from the connect object, you could use `FromSheet` property of the connect object. To get the shape to which it is connected, you can use the `ToSheet` property. To list all connectors, you can just list all shapes, and filter those which are connectors (1-d)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean as `connector` Visio's object [Dynamic connector](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/all-you-need-to-know-about-visio-desktop-connectors/ba-p/291485) you can use [CreateSelection method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.createselection)…

Iterate connectors via master-shape (type of selection **visSelTypeByMaster**)

```
Dim sl As Selection, shp As Shape, mast As Master
Set mast = ActiveDocument.Masters("Dynamic connector")
Set sl = ActivePage.CreateSelection(visSelTypeByMaster, visSelModeSkipSuper, mast)
For i = 1 To sl.Count
    Set shp = sl.Item(i)
    shp.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineWeight).FormulaU = "6 pt"
Next
```

Or iterate connectors via layer (type of selection **visSelTypeByLayer**)

```
Dim sl As Selection, shp As Shape
Set sl = ActivePage.CreateSelection(visSelTypeByLayer, , "Connector")
For i = 1 To sl.Count
    Set shp = sl.Item(i)
    shp.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineWeight).FormulaU = "6 pt"
Next
```

**PS**

> I get an "object required" error.

you must use syntax

```
Set shp = connnn.FromSheet
```

Comment: I've found the problem... What I was looking for was not in the set of connectors! It's the shapes such as `shape.oneD = True` . Spent days on this!

Answer (score 0):

*** THIS DOES NOT WORK IN ALL CASES, INVESTIGATING FURTHER

Using Surrogate's solution, based on the Selection object, I could find no way of getting to the connectors that were inside groups.
I found a parameter of shape that seems to provide the required info: `shape.fillStyle`. With connectors, it takes the value `"Connector"`. This is not clearly stated in the documentation, so your comments are welcome as to limitations of this approach.

Anyway, I wrote a set of functions that uses this parameter.

```
' Sets all shapes to line colors to dark blue, then sets all connectors to dark red
Sub test_all_shapes_and_connectors()
Dim set1, set2 As Collection
Set set1 = get_all_shapes
Set set2 = get_all_connectors
For Each shp In set1
    set_line_color shp, "0,0,127"
Next
For Each shp In set2
    set_line_color shp, "127,0,0"
Next
End Sub

Function get_all_shapes()
    Set get_all_shapes = get_multi_shapes(Application.ActiveWindow.Page.shapes)
End Function

Function get_all_connectors()
    Set get_all_connectors = get_multi_shapes(Application.ActiveWindow.Page.shapes, "Connector")
End Function

' gets all the shapes in the page, including inside groups.
' fillStyleCrit is optional, if omitted the function gets all shapes
' fillStyleCrit = "Connector" selects only connectors ("lines")
Function get_multi_shapes(oldSet, Optional fillStyleCrit As String = "") As Collection
Dim newSet As New Collection
For Each stuffToAdd In oldSet
    If stuffToAdd.Type <> visTypeGroup Then
        If fillStyleCrit = "" Or fillStyleCrit = stuffToAdd.FillStyle Then
            newSet.Add stuffToAdd
            Set get_multi_shapes = newSet
        End If
    ElseIf stuffToAdd.Type = visTypeGroup Then
        For Each subshp In stuffToAdd.shapes
            newSet.Add subshp
        Next
        Set get_multi_shapes = get_multi_shapes(newSet)
    End If
Next
End Function


Function set_line_color(shp, rgb1)
On Error GoTo exit_set_line_color
    Dim s, newColor As String
    s = simple_RGB(rgb1)
    newColor = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(" + s + "))"
    Debug.Print ("setting line color to " + newColor)
    shp.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineColor).FormulaU = newColor
exit_set_line_color:
End Function
```